# Trouble passing array variable to BigQuery query from shell

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to run parametrized queries from a shell script and I need to be able to provide parameters.

This is the command I'm trying to run :

```
bq --location=US query --use_legacy_sql=False \
--parameter='gender::M' \
--parameter='states:ARRAY<STRING>:["WA", "WI", "WV", "WY"]' \
'SELECT name, sum(number) as count
FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013`
WHERE gender = @gender
AND state IN UNNEST(@states)
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 10;'
```

If you copy/paste as it is in a shell, it works.
Now, this is what I'm trying to run :

In a file *script.sh*

```
runQuery(){

    states="'$1'"

    bq --location=US query --use_legacy_sql=False --parameter='gender::M' --parameter=$states \
        'SELECT name, sum(number) as count
        FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013`
        WHERE gender = @gender
        AND state IN UNNEST(@states)
        GROUP BY name
        ORDER BY count DESC
        LIMIT 10;'
    }

runQuery 'states:ARRAY<STRING>:["WA", "WI", "WV", "WY"]'
```

But this doesn't work.

Here's the error log :

[image]

I am pretty sure it has to do with the fact that the parameter has both single quotes and double quotes and at some points something goes wrong when processing *'states:ARRAY:["WA", "WI", "WV", "WY"]'* but I just can't find how to solve this.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Found the error :

Changed `runQuery 'states:ARRAY<STRING>:["WA", "WI", "WV", "WY"]'`

To `runQuery 'states:ARRAY<STRING>:["WA","WI","WV","WY"]'`

Note that blank spaces were removed from the array.